# Removing individuals from dataframe if variable doesn't match another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Person_ID = c(123L, 123L, 444L, 444L), Procedure_Date = c("12/12/12", 
"12/12/13", "5/5/13", "6/30/13")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

However, I have to filter the dataframe to only look at individuals who had a procedure done in the year 2013.

Post filtering, the dataframe should look like this:

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(Person_ID = c(123L, 444L, 444L), Procedure_Date = c("12/12/13", 
"5/5/13", "6/30/13")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

As you can see, `Person_ID`=123 had their first procedure filtered out, whereas `Person_ID`=444 did not.
In my current dataframe, I would like to remove `Person_ID`=123 since their first procedure date is cut off post-filtering.

Is there an easy way to do this? I have a large dataframe so it would take a long time to manually search.

Comment: To clarify, do you only want rows of `df` with year 2013, or only individuals where ALL their dates are 2013, or something else? You say "I would like to remove Person_ID=123," but you only remove one of their rows, is that intended?

Comment: I want to be able to easily see if I am cutting of an individual's first procedure date after I filter to only see 2013 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it will be easier to work with dates if we convert to the Date data type.

```
df$Procedure_Date2 = as.Date(df$Procedure_Date, "%m/%d/%y")
```

Then it sounds like you want to do some analysis on a per-ID basis. We might do that in dplyr in a few ways. We could identify the first year per ID:

```
library(dplyr) # v1.1.0 or later for .by, otherwise group_by(Person_ID) first
df %>%
  summarize(first_proc_yr = min(lubridate::year(Procedure_Date2)), .by = Person_ID)

## A tibble: 2 × 2
#  Person_ID first_proc_yr
#      <int>         <dbl>
#1       123          2012
#2       444          2013
```

Or we might see for each person which # procedure was first done post-2013:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Person_ID) %>%
  mutate(proc_number = row_number()) %>%
  filter(Procedure_Date2 >= as.Date("2013-01-01")) %>%
  slice_min(proc_number)


# A tibble: 2 × 4
# Groups:   Person_ID [2]
  Person_ID Procedure_Date Procedure_Date2 proc_number
      <int> <chr>          <date>                <int>
1       123 12/12/13       2013-12-12                2
2       444 5/5/13         2013-05-05                1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extra column with the extracted year using `year` from `lubridate` after having it in a date format and `filter` based on year like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate(year = year(as.Date(Procedure_Date, "%m/%d/%y"))) %>%
  filter(year == 2013) %>%
  select(-year)
#>   Person_ID Procedure_Date
#> 1       123       12/12/13
#> 2       444         5/5/13
#> 3       444        6/30/13
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>